# Equality of mappings under ZFC

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

A mapping from $X$ to $Y$ is defined as a subset $f \subseteq X\times Y$ such that $\forall x\in X,\exists!y\in Y : (x,y)\in f$ (i.e. $\exists y\in Y : (x,y)\in f \land (\forall y,y'\in Y, (x,y)\in f \land (x,y')\in f \Rightarrow y=y')$).
Moreover, this mapping is denoted as $f : X\to Y$ and $f(x)=y \Leftrightarrow (x,y)\in f$

So, let $f : X\to Y$ and $g : X\to Y$ be mappings, how to prove that
$$ f= g \Leftrightarrow \forall x\in X , f(x)=g(x)$$
I've already proved the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ , but for inverse implication $(\Leftarrow)$ I don't see how ?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: What is $E$? $E=X$?

Comment: Sorry, it must be $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: $f \subseteq g$. Indeed, if $(x,y) \in f$ then $f(x) = y$, so $g(x) = y$, so $(x,y) \in g$.

Now just reverse the reasoning.